# Add Empty Row(For Insert) in jquery Datatable (Not Editor) in bottom after data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

my question is not how to put the empty row its why the empty row appear as first row

```
   function BindCenterTable(ID,val) {
        var strSearchLang = " ";
        txtCenetrTotal.value = val;
        if (lang == 'en-US') {
            strSearchLang = "  Search   ";
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: 'Query.asmx/FillSubTransCenters',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{SubTransID: ' + ID + '}',


            success: function (data) {
                if (typeof CenterTable != 'undefined')
                    CenterTable.destroy();
                CenterTable = $('#tableCenters').DataTable({
                    "aaData": JSON.parse(data.d),
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "lengthChange": false,
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sSearch": strSearchLang
                    },
                    "paging": false,
                    "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" }, { "data": "Center_No" },
                    { "data": "CenterName" }, { "data": "Value" },
                    { "data": "Val_Percent" }
                    ],
                    "columnDefs": [
         {
             "targets": [0],
             "visible": false,
             "searchable": false
         }, {
             "targets": 5,
             "data": null,
             "defaultContent":
              ' <button class="btn btnEdit" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-pencil " style="font-size:20px"></i> </button> <button class="btn btnDelete" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-trash " style="font-size:20px"></i> </button>'

         }
                    ],

                });
                AddCenterEmptyRow();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                // alert(err);
            }
        })
    }



 function AddCenterEmptyRow() {
        var rowNode = CenterTable.row.add({
            "id": "0", "Center_No": "0", "CenterName": "0",
            "Value": "0", "Val_Percent": "0"
        }).draw().node();
        if (rowNode) {
            var jqTds = $('>td', rowNode);
            jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<table style="width:100%"><tr><td><input type="button" id="btnNewCenter"   value="..." ></td><td><input type="text" class="twitterStyleTextbox" style="width:60px" id="txtNewCenter_No" readonly ></td></tr></table>';
            jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="twitterStyleTextbox" readonly id="txtNewCenterName" >';
            jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="number" style="width:60px" id="txtNewCenterVal" class="twitterStyleTextbox">';
            jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="number" style="width:60px" id="txtNewCenterPerc" class="twitterStyleTextbox">';
            jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<button class="btn btnSubNewCenterSave" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-save " style="font-size:20px"></i> </button> '
        }
        var e = document.getElementById('txtNewCenterVal');
        e.oninput = CenterValChange;
        e.onpropertychange = e.oninput; // for IE8
        var e = document.getElementById('txtNewCenterPerc');
        e.oninput = CenterPercChange;
        e.onpropertychange = e.oninput; // for IE8
        //var e = document.getElementById('txtNewEchange_Rate');
        //e.oninput = DebitChange;
        //e.onpropertychange = e.oninput; // for IE8
    }
```

every thing works fine but the data appear after the empty row
1-is there a way to select the order where to put the empty row
2- is there a better way for inserting an empty row

Note : i can not use the footer because it is used for summery but that code is not included

Thank you

Edit

[image]

Comment: is `>td` correct? Also, could you show the expected result and what you're getting?

Comment: I have sent a picture Empty row should be after all data rows

Comment: did you look [at this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html)?

Comment: i need the empty row not to be ordered (what if the user order with other column) i want it fixed to bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the creator of Datatables answering a [related question](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23988/how-do-you-add-a-row-via-rows-add-at-the-bottom-of-the-table):

> The row will be positioned according to the ordering applied to the
>   table. Where ever the table's ordering positions the row, that is
>   where it will appear.

My solution would be to use the [sorting](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) functionality to do this

Here is a [live example](http://live.datatables.net/qelajomi/1/edit) of what i would do...

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank You for the answer but as you see from my code i didn't use order and the values of the new row is all zeros and the emptyrowfunction is called after the bind of the data so i think (by logic) the empty row should be after the data -- is there any other method because i will use the order in other function and yet the user can order so i don't want the empty row to be ordered with data rows (fixed at bottom)

Comment: i got an idea can i make it in the footer but the question is i alredy have a footer row can i have a footer with two rows(sum , empty row)

Comment: Example or link Please ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need jquery for this just put it in the footer `<tfoot></tfoot>` of your HTML table.